# type Null is not a subtype of type 'MyColor' Inherited Widget (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

**I used Inherited Widget and when I use it it tells me that there is a problem with context even though it has its own builder**

> Is it mandatory to have a key in the super ?

[image]

```
class MyColor extends InheritedWidget{
   Key? key ;
  final Color color ;
  final Widget child ;
  MyColor({required this.color , required this.child}) : super(child: child) ;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(covariant MyColor oldWidget) {
   return color != oldWidget.color ;
  }
static MyColor of(context)=>
    context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MyColor>();
}
```

```
 Builder(builder: (ctx) {
          return MyColor(
            color: Colors.teal,
            child:  Text(
              'Text Color Inherited',
              style: TextStyle(color: MyColor?.of(ctx).color),
            ),
          );
        }),
```

Answer (score 0):

**The solution to the problem is to surround the text with the Builder and the Text takes the ctx
,Not the MyColor**

```
  child:  MyColor(
            color: Colors.teal,
            child:  Builder(
              builder: (ctx) {
                return Text(
                  'Text Color Inherited',
                  style: TextStyle(color: MyColor.of(ctx).color),
                );
              }
            ),
          ),
```